# Multiple testing in mixed effect model vs Bayesian approach

Tags: bayesian, mixed-model, multiple-comparisons

I am analyzing a randomized dataset (group A,B and C) containing multiple continuous values for each ID gathered over several days (t={0,1,2,3 and 4}) using a frequentist mixed linear model with each ID as a random-effect.

Now, my co-investigators are insisting on a table providing confidence intervals and p-values for each pair of groups (A vs B, B vs C and A vs C) for every timepoint resulting in 15 hypotheses being tested in this table alone. I guess I could calculate the p-values and confidence intervals for the differences using the functionality from either the marginaleffects or emmeans package, but I guess this would inflate the chance of type-I errors - Would you consider it sufficient to provide Tukey corrected p-values for all these tests, is there another method that is considered more adequate or should I abandon the idea of multiple testing altogether?

I guess it is controversial, but doing this in a Bayesian framework and instead subtracting the posterior distributions for each pair and reporting the proportion >0, could that be a way of addressing the multiple testing?

Comment: You can use a Tukey correction for *each* set of 3 pairwise comparisons, but you cannot use a Tukey correction for *all* 15 comparisons, because the underlying assumption is that you have *one* set of pairwise comparisons. Personally, I think using Tukey separately for each set is reasonable.

Comment: Any idea of whether the p-values calculated with the following command are adjusted for multiplicity? `marginaleffects::comparisons(mod,variables =  list(group="pairwise"),by="time")`

Comment: I imagine that if it is, it is explained in the documentation for `marginaleffects::comparisons`.

Comment: No hint of it in the documentation, which was confirmed later by the author.